# Spring SessionFactory creation domain objects auto scanning

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, dependency-injection

In my spring dao configuration xml I currently have to manually list out the domain classes names. Is there any way to automate this to eliminate the need to manually list out a domain class whenever a new one is created?

To give a better idea of what I want to do this, using something similar to component-scan or such

Current code

```
<bean id="daoSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="applicationDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.greenwhich.application.domain.Driver</value>
            <value>com.greenwhich.application.domain.DriverRealTimeCurrentLocation</value>
            <value>com.greenwhich.application.domain.Journey</value>
            <value>com.greenwhich.application.domain.Customer</value>
            <value>com.greenwhich.application.domain.SystemConstants</value>
            <value>com.greenwhich.application.domain.DriverRequest</value>              
            <value>com.greenwhich.application.domain.Account</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

All I require that the values under the "annotatedClasses" property is automatically detected

Is there any way to implement this? So far I have tried inserting a component-scan inside of the "annotatedClasses" property searching for the "Entity" annotation which did not work

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to replace the annotatedClasses property with:

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.greenwhich.application.domain" />
```

as part of your session factory configuration.